# Get a static class member or return the default value

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template method that creates an instance of a class and also setting a default name for it.

```cpp
template<class T, class ...TArgs>
  requires std::is_base_of_v<px::GameObject, T>
std::shared_ptr<T> px::World::createGameObject(TArgs... args)
{
  EASY_BLOCK(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

  // Allocate enough space
  void *raw = ::operator new(sizeof(T));

  // Get a GameObject ptr
  auto gameObjectPtr = reinterpret_cast<GameObject *>(raw);
  // Set pointer to the world (this)
  gameObjectPtr->m_world = this;

  // Call constructor
  new (raw) T(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);

  // Create a shared pointer.
  auto tPtr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(raw);
  auto gameObject = std::shared_ptr<T>(tPtr);

  // Append it to inner list
  {
    std::lock_guard lk(m_gameObjectsMutex);
    m_gameObjects.push_front(gameObject);
    gameObject->m_self = m_gameObjects.begin();
  }

  constexpr auto name = ...; // I need get default name here

  // Name it
  gameObject->setName(fmt::format(name, ++unnamedUid));

  return gameObject;
}
```

```cpp
class Camera : public GameObject {
  public:
    constexpr inline static std::string_view defaultName = "Camera #{}";

    // ...
  };
```

I know this can be done more easily through some template function and macro, but I was interested in this. I think C++ allows this, but I don't know how.

I tried

```cpp
    template <class T>
    concept HasDefaultName = requires {
      { T::defaultName } -> std::same_as<std::string_view>;
    };

    template <class T>
    inline constexpr std::string_view getObjectDefaultName() {
      if constexpr (HasDefaultName<T>)
        return T::defaultName;
      else
        return "Unnamed object #{}";
    }
```

```cpp
constexpr auto name = priv::getObjectDefaultName<T>();
```

But it always returned the default value.

Comment: By "it always returned the default value" you mean it always returns `T::defaultName` or `"Unnamed object #{}"`? And, generally, it's better to include [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. I.e. try to condense your problem to simple classes/functions whose full definition you can include in your question and which don't include any irrelevant information.

Comment: `std::same_as<std::string_view>` -> `std::same_as<std::string_view const&>` - since constexpr implies const and compound requirements use `decltype((expr))`. There's a duplicate somewhere... And I'd wager you'll find `std::convertible_to<std::string_view>` more useful since it allows some greater flexibility.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thank you! It worked with `std::convertible_to<std::string_view>`